# Search filter not working in Grocery Crud on set_relation column

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working in grocery crud and codeigniter. I am using following relation to fetch records from Questions table of DB.

`$crud->set_relation('pool_id', 'pools', 'Pool {pool_name} ({pool_type})');`

and this is the rendered grid.

[image: Grocery crud grid that I get]

Now when i search the Pools column by using search filters as shown below:

[image]

My question is that why it's not searching for all the records having `Pool A`. Any help?

Answer (score -1):

Because grocery working on Server Side, when you searching data on relation (Pools Field) you must search by the ID not acceptance for the NAME.

Comment: Please do provide a bit code for your answer, by the way that down vote is not mine